# Integral involving complimentary error function.

Tags: probability, integration, error-function

Essentially, I am trying to work out an integral of the form:

$\int_{0}^{\pi }{x\cdot a\cdot \cos \left( x \right)e^{-\left[ a\cdot \sin \left( x \right) \right]^{2}}\mbox{erfc}\left[ -a\cdot \cos \left( x \right) \right]}dx$

or, similarly:

$\int_{0}^{\pi }{x\cdot a\cdot \cos \left( x \right)e^{\left[ a\cdot \cos \left( x \right) \right]^{2}}\mbox{erfc}\left[ -a\cdot \cos \left( x \right) \right]}dx$

It seems like the integral is going to be pretty easy to work out by parts and with a substitution, but it ended up being a little tougher than I expected.  I had almost given up and resorted to numerical methods after trying every trick I know, when I came across this in a table of integrals (http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf):

[image]

Where K is a modified Bessel function of the bth order.  I can't find a derivation of this result so I don't know how to see if I can extend this to my integral.  Any ideas?

(If you are interested in the specifics, I derived a probability density function:
$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi }e^{-\frac{v^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}}+\frac{v\cdot \cos \left( x \right)}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-\left( \frac{v\cdot \sin \left( x \right)}{\sigma \sqrt{2}} \right)^{2}}\mbox{erfc}\left( -\frac{v\cdot \cos \left( x \right)}{\sigma \sqrt{2}} \right), \ \  0\leq x\leq \pi$

and I'm hoping to find the expected value of x, which is given by:
$\mbox{E}\left( X \right)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }{xf\left( x \right)dx}=\frac{\pi }{2}e^{-\frac{v^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}}+\int_{0}^{\pi }{x\frac{v\cdot \cos \left( x \right)}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-\left[ \frac{v\cdot \sin \left( x \right)}{\sigma \sqrt{2}} \right]^{2}}\mbox{erfc}\left[ -\frac{v\cdot \cos \left( x \right)}{\sigma \sqrt{2}} \right]}dx$)

Comment: You can use cos(i*x)=cosh(x) (i the imaginary unit), but you still have that x lurking at the front, and of course the limits... any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I could use that relation (actually the opposite one, where cosh(i*x)=cos(x)), but I'm just not sure where to go from there since the integral table only gives the definite integral, so I can't substitute i*x for x anywhere.  The x in front shouldn't be too bad, since we can use integration by parts.  Oh wait, that means we would have to integrate it twice.  So it is that bad, I guess.  :-/

Comment: You still have to change the limits with some sort of substitution